# Simple tool for callgraph in C++

Tags: c++, static-analysis

Is there are simple tool, which can be used to determine from where a function is called, which other function the function calls ...?

**Edit**: I'm using Mac OS X (10.6) and just want to do static analysis.

Thanks!

Comment: eclipse does this for java, never tried it for c++, but probably does it there too?

Comment: This is typically a feature of the IDE you are using. In Visual Studio 2008, for example, you have "Find all references". (I normally don't use there features in C++ anyway, because I found most of them to be buggy.)

Comment: Simple tool?  Just resolving what a name refers to in C++ is hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)?   Check out 3rd & 4th bullet items on the page:

- functions called by a function
- functions calling a function

It's been a while since I used cscope on C++, I seem to remember it being rock-solid on C code, but not as strong with C++.

Comment: Thanks. Although it only works with C, I could find all wanted to find.

Answer (score 7):

gtags is a tool you can use for doing tagging, but for call tracing as well.

http://www.gnu.org/software/global/

This supports C, C++, Yacc, Java and PHP4.
But it can't handle C++ templates or other complex stuffs properly.

Using this tagging parser, I've made a script to get a call tree from
user's selection through bash completion like the following,
which is displaying a calltree in google profiler code:

```
% global-calltree -x prof_handler Add Evict ProfileData Stop DisableHandler RAW_CHECK WRITE_TO_STDERR
prof_handler:414 => Add:441               |profiler.cc                         |instance_.collector_.Add(depth, stack);
 Add:241 => Evict:290                      |profiledata.cc                      |Evict(*e);
  Evict:61 => ProfileData:75                |profiledata.cc                      |ProfileData::ProfileData()
   ProfileData:124 => Stop:125               |profiledata.cc                      |Stop();
    Stop:261 => DisableHandler:273            |profiler.cc                         |DisableHandler();
     DisableHandler:400 => RAW_CHECK:405       |profiler.cc                         |RAW_CHECK(sigaction(SIGPROF, &sa, NULL) == 0, "sigaction failed");
      RAW_CHECK:83 => WRITE_TO_STDERR:86        |base/logging.h                      |WRITE_TO_STDERR("Check failed: " #condition ": " message "\n",           \
       WRITE_TO_STDERR:59 => DECLARE_int32:65    |base/logging.h                      |DECLARE_int32(verbose);
```

Comment: Care to share this script that uses this tagging parser?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about simple tools, but for free, there's [codeviz](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/codeviz/) (you can read the raw dumps rather than generate graphs if you prefer that). Caveat: all static analysis tools have some problems with virtual calls, and even worse with templates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use mac os, **clang** is a new compiler with static analysis feature.

An example on youtube:
[Finding bugs with clang](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lUJTY373og)